# iOS - Unable to detect app crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, core-data, uiimageview

I am doing an application, and when I try to save data from a UIView to Core Data, it throws an error... I have been more than 5 hours trying some different things, but I am unable to repair it.
I don't think it could be that I am saving it in a bad way, because I use the same method on another UIView and it works perfectly. I had only changed some UITextfields...

This is the error:

> 2014-02-02 18:52:51.937 4Dealrs[3900:70b] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  [ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key . with userInfo {
>       NSTargetObjectUserInfoKey = ">";
>       NSUnknownUserInfoKey = "";
>   }
>   2014-02-02 18:52:51.940 4Dealrs[3900:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key .'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x01b9d5e4 **exceptionPreprocess + 180
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018468b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x01c2d6a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
>       3   Foundation                          0x015078ca -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 282
>       4   Foundation                          0x01474921 _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter + 81
>       5   Foundation                          0x01473f5b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 260
>       6   Foundation                          0x014d56af -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 321
>       7   UIKit                               0x00b310c5 -[UINibKeyValuePair apply] + 70
>       8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018587d2 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
>       9   CoreFoundation                      0x01b98b6a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
>       10  UIKit                               0x00855552 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1389
>       11  UIKit                               0x00698b4b -[UITableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:] + 370
>       12  UIKit                               0x00698e24 -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:] + 48
>       13  UIKit                               0x00698e54 -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 43
>       14  4Dealrs                             0x00014b12 -[SDListaClientesViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 130
>       15  UIKit                               0x006a361f -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 412
>       16  UIKit                               0x006a36f3 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 69
>       17  UIKit                               0x008bf112 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupAnimationsForNewlyInsertedCells] + 8156
>       18  UIKit                               0x008c85ca -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimations] + 143
>       19  UIKit                               0x0068a4bd -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] + 1898
>       20  UIKit                               0x006858e1 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 13534
>       21  UIKit                               0x00695550 -[UITableView _updateRowsAtIndexPaths:updateAction:withRowAnimation:] + 337
>       22  UIKit                               0x0069558f -[UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] + 55
>       23  4Dealrs                             0x0000d4c7 -[CoreDataTableViewController controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:] + 375
>       24  CoreData                            0x00178df2 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 4322
>       25  Foundation                          0x01519bf9 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke + 40
>       26  CoreFoundation                      0x01bf9524 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** + 20
>       27  CoreFoundation                      0x01b5100b _CFXNotificationPost + 2859
>       28  Foundation                          0x01453951 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 98
>       29  CoreData                            0x0007d173 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 83
>       30  CoreData                            0x0011c78f -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:] + 367
>       31  CoreData                            0x00078608 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 2152
>       32  CoreData                            0x00077d99 -[NSManagedObjectContext processPendingChanges] + 41
>       33  CoreData                            0x0004bfe1 _performRunLoopAction + 321
>       34  CoreFoundation                      0x01b654ce **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 30
>       35  CoreFoundation                      0x01b6541f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
>       36  CoreFoundation                      0x01b43344 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
>       37  CoreFoundation                      0x01b42ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
>       38  CoreFoundation                      0x01b428db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
>       39  GraphicsServices                    0x02eb39e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
>       40  GraphicsServices                    0x02eb3809 GSEventRun + 104
>       41  UIKit                               0x005b4d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
>       42  4Dealrs                             0x0000db7d main + 141
>       43  libdyld.dylib                       0x02b5570d start + 1
>       44  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

I have been searching about this error, but I haven't found nothing useful...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stack trace it looks like you have a tableViewCell being instantiated from a NIB file and in the NIB you have an outlet setup for one of the fields which does not have a matching property in the .h/.m file. So double check all your outlets in the tableViewCell NIB file.